# Getting Error "Any one of [**] of transactionSearchFilter cannot be NULL OR Invalid Values

Tags: c#, yodlee

Yodlee API is new for me...

I am trying to get the user account transactions by using `Yodlee REST API` in `C#`.

I used `executeUserSearchRequest` method to get the first page transactions of the user. I referred the [executeUserSearchRequest](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest).

I Passed all the user input, but I am getting the following error:
`{"errorOccured":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException","refrenceCode":"_e651f98b-41c7-48b5-8754-1690a0a23282","message":"Invalid argument value: Any one of userInput of transactionSearchRequest or transacionamount or transactionAmountRange of transactionSearchFilter cannot be NULL OR Invalid Values"}`

Can any one tell me what is the `transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId` and `transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName`?

Please help me to resolve the issue...
Please refer the code below.

```
var request = new RestRequest("/jsonsdk/TransactionSearchService/executeUserSearchRequest", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("cobSessionToken", param.CobrandToken);
request.AddParameter("userSessionToken", param.UserToken);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.containerType", "All");
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber", "5");
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber", "1");
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId", "1");
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName", "DataSearchService");
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType", "ALL_TRANSACTION");
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.ignoreUserInput", "True");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This helped me because I found the /jsonsdk/ which was not mentioned in the https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest documentation page. So Thanks user2930766... Did you get it working? if so perhaps you might be able to guide me with what you did? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the below parameters
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId and transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName

Also
Please add one more parameter as 
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.userInput", "");
in the request and then please try once again.

Also please refer to the Yodlee's sample application and the JAVA doc for clarification

JAVA DOC link

com/yodlee/soap/core/transactionsearch/transactionsearchservice/TransactionSearchService.html

Comment: Shreyans, any chance you can fix that link so that we can read the docs