# I am trying to use Yodlee/executeUserSearchRequest as a RESTful request and need an answer on how to call

Tags: api, rest, yodlee

I am working with the Yodlee services in c# and using the RESTful api. So far I have successfully connected and logged in with my CobrandSession and UserSessionToken in the development environment. I used the sample apps provided in c# and with some advice from shreyans i got an app working. What I got working was 
1) Get YodleeAuthentication
2) Get UserAuthentication
3) Get ItemSummaries

I am now trying to get the full transaction details for each of the Items (i.e. collections of accounts that are an Item)

reading the Docs here https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest it states that I need to call executeUserSearchRequest and then paginate through the results using the getUserTransactions. So I am stuck at this point. I dont really want a search which has parameters I just want ALL transactions for this account that I can see.

However, I am using the variables as defined in that page :-

```
var request = new RestRequest("/jsonsdk/TransactionSearchService/executeUserSearchRequest", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("cobSessionToken", param.CobSessionToken);
request.AddParameter("userSessionToken", param.UserSessionToken);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.containerType", param.ContainerType);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit", param.HigherFetchLimit);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit", param.LowerFetchLimit);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber", param.EndNumber);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber", param.StartNumber);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode", param.CurrencyCode);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate", param.FromDate);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate", param.ToDate);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType.splitType", param.SplitType);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput", param.IgnoreUserInput);
request.AddParameter("transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAcctId", param.ItemAcctId);
var response = RestClientUtil.GetBase().Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
return new YodleeServiceResultDto(content);
```

As per the response from shreyans in this posting [Getting Error "Any one of [**] of transactionSearchFilter cannot be NULL OR Invalid Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650954/getting-error-any-one-of-of-transactionsearchfilter-cannot-be-null-or-inva) I am not putting in the ClientId and the ClientName

The documentation doesn't specify the format of the dates but the example seems to tell me that its american date format. And specifies a parameter saying IgnoreUserinput, but doesnt have a parameter for user input so this is confusing

When I make a call using this format I get an error response

```
var getSearchResult = yodleeExecuteUserSearchRequest.Go(yodleeExecuteUserSearchRequestDto);
getSearchResult.Result="
{"errorOccured":"true","exceptionType":"Exception Occured","refrenceCode":"_60ecb1d7-a4c4-4914-b3cd-49182518ca5d"}"
```

But I get no error message in this and I have no idea what I have done wrong or where to look up this error, can somebody who has used Yodlee REST Api point me in the right direction as I need to get this researched quickly....

thanks your your help, advice, corrections and pointers....

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of parameters which you can try

1)  For a specific ItemAccountId all transactions

```
transactionSearchRequest.containerType=all
transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit=500
transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit=1
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber=1
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber=500
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId=1
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName=DataSearchService
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode=USD
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients=DEFAULT_SERVICE_CLIENT
transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput=true
transactionSearchRequest.ignoreManualTransactions=false
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier=10000353
```

2)  For a Specific account (itemAccountId) with start and end dates

```
transactionSearchRequest.containerType=all
transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit=500
transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit=1
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber=1
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber=500
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId=1
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName=DataSearchService
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode=USD
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients=DEFAULT_SERVICE_CLIENT
transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput=true
transactionSearchRequest.ignoreManualTransactions=false
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier=10000353
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate=08-01-2013
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate=10-31-2013
```